# how to insert html table to a content control in a word template in a document library

Tags: document-library, document-template, richhtmlfield

I have a word template on a document library. It has a rich text context control. I am creating an html table and updating in the same document library 'DescriptionRichText'column. The column is an enhanced rich text. The data is coming properly on that column in a form of a html table. See in the image

[image]

However, when I try to insert that value inside the rich text control. The value comes in html format instead of a table.

Answer (score 0):

The term *RichText* is misleading in this context. Actually the field is of type `Note` (i.e. a very long text) with the `RichText`-option set to true. What this means in SharePoint is that the field will contain HTML and not simple text.

So the answer to your (unspoken) question is: Yes. That is so.

Comment: Thanks Nils for your response. Please suggest how I can bind the data of the column 'DescriptionRichText' to a context control. The data should be shown as a table not in form of HTML tags.

Comment: What kind of controls are you using? Which SharePoint (the image looks like 2007)? What do you mean by "context control"?

Comment: This is sharepoint 2010. Sorry, it is not context control. It is content control. The content controls are added inside word document template of a sharepoint library. The content control is of rich text

Comment: your probably out of luck, then. As I said the field in SharePoint is only named _RichText_ but really it's `HTML`. I'm not good with word but I'm guessing it is impossible to do a HTML-to-RichText conversion in word.